# Proving convergence theorem on power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, divergent-series, formal-power-series

When proving convergence of power series, one encounters the following term:

$$\left( 1 + \delta \right)\frac{\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$

where $\delta>0$, and the claim is that this term is greater than one from the definition of $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sup_{k\geq n}(a_k)$. But I do not see that.

Note: The statement and proof of divergence goes as this:

The series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ diverges on $[z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|>R]$ with $R=\frac{1}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$.

Let now $R\in(0,\infty)$, then we can write $|z|=(1+\delta)R$, with $\delta>0$, one has:

$$
|a_k z^k| = |a_k| |z|^k = \left( \left(1+\delta\right) \frac{\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}\right)^k
$$

And now one is supposed to use the fact that the inside of the bracket is greater than 1 for infinitely many indices $k$.

Note, that there is no assumption on the $[a_k]$ other than $[a_k]\in\mathbb{C}$.

PS: Can someone put in comments, how to write curly braces here? Standard escaping with backslash is not working.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for curly brackets $\{ x\}$. In fact, [here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: @Shaun I was using this `$\{ x \}$` but it was showing as ${x}$ when typing, it might be an issue of the live preview then.

Comment: It's the preview, then; I have similar troubles. Try using the [MathJax sandboxes on the meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/104041) instead. Be sure to use one of its free answers, since, if you start a new one, you'll be inundated with notifications!

Answer (score 3):

Let $L:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ and $L':=\frac L{1+\delta}.$ Since $L'<L,$ by definition of the $\limsup,$ $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L'$ for infinitely many indices $k.$ For these $k$'s, we have $$(1+\delta)\frac{\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}=\frac{\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}{L'}>1.$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Your last inequality is valid regardless of definition of $\lim\sup$, given your definitions. Also I am not sure that I understand how it  would imply that $(1+\delta)\frac{\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}>1$?

Comment: I added a sentence to answer your 2nd "not sureness". About the 1st one, what do you mean "regardless of definition of limsup"? I really use it. The last inequality is only true for infintely many $k$'s (not all) and it is true only because $ L'$ is strictly smaller than the limsup.

Comment: If you define $L' = \frac{L}{1+\delta}$ then, as $L' < L$ regardless of what $L$ is defined, unless I misunderstood the sentence and the comma after $\lim\sup$ is not a typo and you are saying the the definition of limes superior implies that from some $k_0$ we have that $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L'$ for $k\geq k_0$. I was reading that you were saying $\lim\sup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L'$ and I somehow assumed the comma was a typo and you meant $k\to\infty$. My mistake, this makes obviously sense what you wrote.

Comment: 1) I could not be saying $\lim\sup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L',$ since the inequality was followed by "for infinitely many indices $k$". 2) Beware and study the notion of limsup! This does *not* imply "that from some $k_0$
 we have that $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L′$
 for $k≥k_0.$ We only have that for infinitely many $k$'s.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand it at all. I have been looking at definition of $\lim\sup$ for quite some time. Can you be more explicit at arguing why $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}>L'$ "from the definition of $\lim\sup$ for infinitely many $k$'s? $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{ \sqrt[m]{|a_m|}: m\geq n \}$. E.g. if $a_k$ is non-negative, monotonically increasing, isn't $ \sup\{ \sqrt[n]{|a_m|}\}= \infty$?

Comment: [limsup and liminf and it's relation to number of the indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977543)